# Change jsp href element, c:url

Tags: javascript, jquery, spring, jsp

i have this element which on click downloads file.

```
     <a href="<c:url value='/fileDownload?purchaseId=18&id=30&type=txt' />"  id="properties">download</a>
```

Which is genereated from spring and i change it with jquery

```
$('#properties').attr('href',model.data);
```

but the problem is when href is generated C:url adds

```
/mysite/fileDownload?purpurchaseId=18&id=30&type=txt
```

and when i generate the `/mysite/` is missing.

How can i fix this ? I am not very familiar with jsp.

To simplify
i want to change the href element purchaseId and id. How to do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@Autowired
private ApplicationContext appContext;
```

Since you are using spring for getting the ids, get the context path from there and add it to your string.

```
String contextpath = appContext.getApplicationName();
```

Answer (score 1):

change the link to

```
${pageContext.request.contextPath}/fileDownload?purchaseId=18&id=30&type=txt
```

to include context path

Comment: where do i add this ${pageContext.request.contextPath}